# How to get the real client ip by usig nginx in docker

Tags: c#, docker, nginx, .net-core

I use a .NET Core backend, an angular frontend and a nginx as a reverse proxy in a docker network. I call the frontend from the browser locally or from another client in the same LAN. Therefore there is no additional proxy in use. I now try to determine the real IP address of the client. I get several unknown IP addresses, which I can't ping, but not the one of the client.

What am I doing wrong or what have I forgotten?

Here a part of the Startup.cs:

```
virtual public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    });

    ...
}

virtual public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
        ForwardLimit = null, // null = disable check
        RequireHeaderSymmetry = false,
        //KnownProxies = { IPAddress.Parse("<IP Adresse 1>")},
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();           
}
```

Here the nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /etc/nginx/logs/error.log;

events { 
}

http {

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
    }

  upstream ${SERVER_NAME} {
    server backend_app:4200;
    server 127.0.0.1:4200;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl; 

    server_name ${SERVER_NAME};
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://${SERVER_NAME};
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}
```

Reduced docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontproxy:
    networks:
      frontproxy_default: {}
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.165.137
  application_app:    
    networks:
      frontproxy_default: {}
      test_network: {}   
  application_sql:    
    networks:
      - test_network   
  application_api:    
    container_name: api
    networks:
      - test_network

networks:
  test_network:
    name: test_network
  frontproxy_default:
    name: frontproxy_default
  public_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
          #gateway: 192.168.165.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you want to control the IP addresses of docker images, a better idea is to set up the entire orchestration yourself.

Docker-compose yaml file gives you the option to set IP Address yourself.

docker-compose provisions a network by default and assigns ip address by itself. You can override the default network with a custom one.

The new `docker-compose.yaml` file should resemble like below:

In my case DB is mysql server, API is the .NET Core WebAPI project. WEB1/2 Are two frontend server, again .NET Core MVC Project for me.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  moviedb:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password@123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: moviedb
      MYSQL_USER: movieadmin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password@123
    volumes:
      - C:\MvcMovie:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./MvcMovie/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:ro
    networks:
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: ${MVCMOVIE_DB_1_IP}
  movieapi:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
    depends_on:
      - moviedb
    networks:
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: ${MVCMOVIE_API_1_IP}
  movieweb1:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.web
    networks:
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: ${MVCMOVIE_WEB_1_IP}
  movieweb2:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.web
    networks:
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: ${MVCMOVIE_WEB_2_IP}
  haproxy:
    image: haproxy
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    expose:
      - 80
    networks:
      public_net:
         ipv4_address: ${HA_PROXY_IP}
    environment:
      - MVCMOVIE_API_1_IP=${MVCMOVIE_API_1_IP}
      - MVCMOVIE_WEB_1_IP=${MVCMOVIE_WEB_1_IP}
      - MVCMOVIE_WEB_2_IP=${MVCMOVIE_WEB_2_IP}
      - MVCMOVIE_EXPOSED_PORT=${MVCMOVIE_EXPOSED_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
networks:
  public_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: ${NETWORK_SUBNET}
```

*Pay special attention to indentation.*

Add a .env file next to docker-compose.yaml and use similar content like below. Change names and port to suit needs.

```
MVCMOVIE_EXPOSED_PORT=80

MVCMOVIE_DB_1_IP=192.168.0.10

MVCMOVIE_API_1_IP=192.168.0.20

MVCMOVIE_WEB_1_IP=192.168.0.30
MVCMOVIE_WEB_2_IP=192.168.0.31


HA_PROXY_IP=192.168.0.100

NETWORK_SUBNET=192.168.0.0/24
```

With that said. you should never code against IP addresses. 
If I were you I'd do one of the below:

1. Use service names instead.
2. Put settings of IP Address in a .env file and use an environment variable in places of ipv4_address: ${server1_ip_address} or something similar.
3. Consider using Kubernetes. Make your backend servers sit behind a load-balancer.

Good luck.

Comment: I added your points to my docker-compose (see in my posting). As the IP adress of nginx-proxy I used the real IP of the server. But as the X-Forwarded-For-IP-adress I got now the gateway-adress of the server, not the IP of the client. I tried to add the gateway, but I get an "unexpected" error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: quick observations. for a subnet 192.168.0.0/24 the ip address you used for front proxy: 192.168.165.137 is not correct. You can only have 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.0.255.
Question: Why do you need the ip address of the front end server for?

Comment: A few suggestions would be to add ports to your yaml file and that'll expose the correct ports.

Comment: I used 192.168.165.137 because you wrote ${server1_ip_address} and that's the IP-address of the server in our LAN. :-) What else could be correct?

Comment: In docker you always have to pay attention to what side of network you are on.
On your local system there is a separate network.
There is a new network when you add docker-compose.yaml.
The only bridge between local computer LAN and network inside docker is the ports command in yaml or -p 8000:80 for example.
If you want to launch shell for each of these.. you'll have to expose ports for all the containers frontend, backend, database etc.